# How to detect heap corruption bug in Android Studio

Tags: android, c++, java-native-interface

I have a bug in my mobile app which makes the app crash. According to the dumpstate_app_native.txt file it looks like the bug has something to do with heap corruption. I don't have a certain pattern to check where my application crashes. It could happen any time during the life-cycle of the app. I have tried gdb but it hasn't helped me that much.

### The following is where the app crashes. If anyone has ever experienced the similar issue I appreciate it if you share your thoughts with me.

```
heap corruption detected by tmalloc_small
F/libc    (15213): Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT) at 0x00003b6d (code=-6), thread 15300 (Thread-762)
W/droidpmx(15213):  HTTPAPI THREAD -connection table quit loop
D/CustomFrequencyManagerService(  781): releaseDVFSLockLocked : Getting Lock type frm List : DVFS_MIN_LIMIT  frequency : 1190400  uid : 10032  pid : 1176  tag : LAUNCHER_APP_BOOSTER_CPU@149
D/CustomFrequencyManagerService(  781): FrequencyrequestList.getNextMaxCPUCoreRequest, index: 0
I/SELinux (  231): Function: selinux_android_load_priority [0], There is no sepolicy file.
I/SELinux (  231):  
I/SELinux (  231): Function: selinux_android_load_priority [1], There is no sepolicy version file.
I/SELinux (  231):  
I/SELinux (  231): Function: selinux_android_load_priority , priority version is VE=SEPF_SM-T530NU_4.4.2_0037
I/SELinux (  231):  
I/SELinux (  231):  
I/SELinux (  231): get_selabel_handle: file_contexts is loaded from /file_contexts
I/DEBUG   (  231): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
I/DEBUG   (  231): Build fingerprint: 'samsung/matissewifiue/matissewifiue:4.4.2/KOT49H/T530NUUEU1AOA2:user/release-keys'
I/DEBUG   (  231): Revision: '6'
I/DEBUG   (  231): pid: 15213, tid: 15300, name: Thread-762  >>> com.securus.videoclient <<<
I/DEBUG   (  231): signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL), fault addr --------
I/DEBUG   (  231): Abort message: 'heap corruption detected by tmalloc_small'
I/DEBUG   (  231):     r0 00000000  r1 00003bc4  r2 00000006  r3 00000000
I/DEBUG   (  231):     r4 00000006  r5 00000016  r6 00003bc4  r7 0000010c
I/DEBUG   (  231):     r8 000008f4  r9 60000004  sl 40112000  fp 00000000
I/DEBUG   (  231):     ip 00000000  sp 7cc5e4a8  lr 401291ad  pc 40138154  cpsr 00000010
I/DEBUG   (  231):     d0  0000000000000000  d1  0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (  231):     d2  0000000000000000  d3  0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (  231):     d4  372d353432412d30  d5  3341454337394641
I/DEBUG   (  231):     d6  6338007273333536  d7  72756365732e6d6f
I/DEBUG   (  231):     d8  0000000000000000  d9  0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (  231):     d10 0000000000000000  d11 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (  231):     d12 0000000000000000  d13 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (  231):     d14 0000000000000000  d15 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (  231):     d16 726f632070616568  d17 206e6f6974707572
I/DEBUG   (  231):     d18 0063002f00610074  d19 0073002e006d006f
I/DEBUG   (  231):     d20 0072007500630065  d21 0076002e00730075
I/DEBUG   (  231):     d22 006f006500640069  d23 00650069006c0063
I/DEBUG   (  231):     d24 0000000000000000  d25 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (  231):     d26 0000000000000000  d27 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (  231):     d28 0100010001000100  d29 0100010001000100
I/DEBUG   (  231):     d30 0000000000000000  d31 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (  231):     scr 60000012
I/DEBUG   (  231): 
I/DEBUG   (  231): backtrace:
I/DEBUG   (  231):     #00  pc 00022154  /system/lib/libc.so (tgkill+12)
I/DEBUG   (  231):     #01  pc 000131a9  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_kill+48)
I/DEBUG   (  231):     #02  pc 000133bd  /system/lib/libc.so (raise+10)
I/DEBUG   (  231):     #03  pc 000120f3  /system/lib/libc.so
I/DEBUG   (  231):     #04  pc 00021a08  /system/lib/libc.so (abort+4)
I/DEBUG   (  231):     #05  pc 00012bd9  /system/lib/libc.so
I/DEBUG   (  231):     #06  pc 0000f2e5  /system/lib/libc.so
I/DEBUG   (  231):     #07  pc 000101f1  /system/lib/libc.so (dlmalloc+604)
I/DEBUG   (  231):     #08  pc 0000dd1f  /system/lib/libc.so (malloc+10)
I/DEBUG   (  231):     #09  pc 00041055  /system/lib/libicuuc.so
I/DEBUG   (  231):     #10  pc 000416af  /system/lib/libicuuc.so (ures_getByKeyWithFallback_51+438)
I/DEBUG   (  231):     #11  pc 000e1b19  /system/lib/libicui18n.so
I/DEBUG   (  231):     #12  pc 00057a9b  /system/lib/libsqlite.so (register_android_functions+18)
I/DEBUG   (  231):     #13  pc 00065d19  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so
I/DEBUG   (  231):     #14  pc 00020d0c  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmPlatformInvoke+112)
I/DEBUG   (  231):     #15  pc 00051a67  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallJNIMethod(unsigned int const*, JValue*, Method const*, Thread*)+398)
I/DEBUG   (  231):     #16  pc 0002a1a0  /system/lib/libdvm.so
I/DEBUG   (  231):     #17  pc 00031650  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmMterpStd(Thread*)+76)
I/DEBUG   (  231):     #18  pc 0002ece8  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmInterpret(Thread*, Method const*, JValue*)+184)
I/DEBUG   (  231):     #19  pc 00063fb5  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallMethodV(Thread*, Method const*, Object*, bool, JValue*, std::__va_list)+336)
I/DEBUG   (  231):     #20  pc 00063fd9  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallMethod(Thread*, Method const*, Object*, JValue*, ...)+20)
I/DEBUG   (  231):     #21  pc 00058cab  /system/lib/libdvm.so
I/DEBUG   (  231):     #22  pc 0000d298  /system/lib/libc.so (__thread_entry+72)
I/DEBUG   (  231):     #23  pc 0000d430  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_create+240)
I/DEBUG   (  231): 
I/DEBUG   (  231): stack:
I/DEBUG   (  231):          7cc5e468  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  231):          7cc5e46c  40127033  /system/lib/libc.so (dlmalloc+4254)
I/DEBUG   (  231):          7cc5e470  0000b31a  
I/DEBUG   (  231):          7cc5e474  00060282  
I/DEBUG   (  231):          7cc5e478  41720a21  /system/lib/libdvm.so
I/DEBUG   (  231):          7cc5e47c  41784ea0  /system/lib/libdvm.so
I/DEBUG   (  231):          7cc5e480  7b0a95c0  
I/DEBUG   (  231):          7cc5e484  7b0a95c8  
I/DEBUG   (  231):          7cc5e488  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  231):          7cc5e48c  7b0a95c8  
I/DEBUG   (  231):          7cc5e490  7bdba390  
I/DEBUG   (  231):          7cc5e494  4012741f  /system/lib/libc.so (dlfree+50)
I/DEBUG   (  231):          7cc5e498  40160000  /system/lib/libc.so
I/DEBUG   (  231):          7cc5e49c  41e4c1b0  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-heap (deleted)
I/DEBUG   (  231):          7cc5e4a0  41e4c1b0  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-heap (deleted)
I/DEBUG   (  231):          7cc5e4a4  7b0a95c8  
I/DEBUG   (  231):     #00  7cc5e4a8  00000006  
I/DEBUG   (  231):          7cc5e4ac  00000016  
I/DEBUG   (  231):          7cc5e4b0  00003bc4  
I/DEBUG   (  231):          7cc5e4b4  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  231):          7cc5e4b8  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  231):          7cc5e4bc  401291ad  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_kill+52)
I/DEBUG   (  231):     #01  7cc5e4c0  00000006  
I/DEBUG   (  231):          7cc5e4c4  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  231):          7cc5e4c8  78aec638  
I/DEBUG   (  231):          7cc5e4cc  401293c1  /system/lib/libc.so (raise+14)
I/DEBUG   (  231):     #02  7cc5e4d0  7cc5e4dc  [stack:15300]
I/DEBUG   (  231):          7cc5e4d4  401280f7  /system/lib/libc.so
I/DEBUG   (  231): 
I/DEBUG   (  231): memory near r1:
I/DEBUG   (  231):     00003ba4 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
I/DEBUG   (  231):     00003bb4 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
I/DEBUG   (  231):     00003bc4 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
I/DEBUG   (  231):     00003bd4 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
I/DEBUG   (  231):     00003be4 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
I/DEBUG   (  231):     00003bf4 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
I/DEBUG   (  231):     00003c04 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
I/DEBUG   (  231):     00003c14 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
I/DEBUG   (  231):     00003c24 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
I/DEBUG   (  231):     00003c34 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
I/DEBUG   (  231):     00003c44 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
I/DEBUG   (  231):     00003c54 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
I/DEBUG   (  231):     00003c64 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
I/DEBUG   (  231):     00003c74 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
I/DEBUG   (  231):     00003c84 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
I/DEBUG   (  231):     00003c94 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
I/DEBUG   (  231): 
I/DEBUG   (  231): memory near r6:
I/DEBUG   (  231):     00003ba4 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
I/DEBUG   (  231):     00003bb4 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
I/DEBUG   (  231):     00003bc4 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
I/DEBUG   (  231):     00003bd4 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
I/DEBUG   (  231):     00003be4 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
I/DEBUG   (  231):     00003bf4 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
I/DEBUG   (  231):     00003c04 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
I/DEBUG   (  231):     00003c14 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
I/DEBUG   (  231):     00003c24 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
I/DEBUG   (  231):     00003c34 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
I/DEBUG   (  231):     00003c44 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
I/DEBUG   (  231):     00003c54 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
I/DEBUG   (  231):     00003c64 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
I/DEBUG   (  231):     00003c74 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
I/DEBUG   (  231):     00003c84 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
I/DEBUG   (  231):     00003c94 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
I/DEBUG   (  231): 
I/DEBUG   (  231): memory near r9:
I/DEBUG   (  231):     5fffffe4 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  231):     5ffffff4 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  231):     60000004 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  231):     60000014 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  231):     60000024 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  231):     60000034 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  231):     60000044 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  231):     60000054 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  231):     60000064 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  231):     60000074 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  231):     60000084 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  231):     60000094 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  231):     600000a4 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  231):     600000b4 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  231):     600000c4 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  231):     600000d4 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  231): 
I/DEBUG   (  231): memory near sl:
I/DEBUG   (  231):     40111fe0 40111ed8 402b0ec4 40111eb8 40111c70  
I/DEBUG   (  231):     40111ff0 00000001 402af000 00000100 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  231):     40112000 00000000 0000001b 401600e0 401600e0  
I/DEBUG   (  231):     40112010 401252b1 40125a29 401252c1 0000001b  
I/DEBUG   (  231):     40112020 00000010 00000001 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  231):     40112030 00000000 0000001b 00000025 00000002  
I/DEBUG   (  231):     40112040 00000000 00000000 00000000 0000001b  
I/DEBUG   (  231):     40112050 401b5a30 40112078 00000002 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  231):     40112060 00000008 0000003b 00000001 00000020  
I/DEBUG   (  231):     40112070 00000000 00000000 40177309 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  231):     40112080 4026185d ffffd8f0 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  231):     40112090 00000000 00000000 00000000 0000002b  
I/DEBUG   (  231):     401120a0 00000001 0000000e 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  231):     401120b0 00700061 006f0070 00730070 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  231):     401120c0 00000000 0000006b 00000001 00000052  
I/DEBUG   (  231):     401120d0 00000000 00000000 006f0063 002e006d  
I/DEBUG   (  231): 
I/DEBUG   (  231): memory near sp:
I/DEBUG   (  231):     7cc5e488 00000000 7b0a95c8 7bdba390 4012741f  
I/DEBUG   (  231):     7cc5e498 40160000 41e4c1b0 41e4c1b0 7b0a95c8  
I/DEBUG   (  231):     7cc5e4a8 00000006 00000016 00003bc4 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  231):     7cc5e4b8 00000000 401291ad 00000006 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  231):     7cc5e4c8 78aec638 401293c1 7cc5e4dc 401280f7  
I/DEBUG   (  231):     7cc5e4d8 0000b31a ffffffdf 00000000 00060282  
I/DEBUG   (  231):     7cc5e4e8 000081b0 00000001 000027bf 00000090  
I/DEBUG   (  231):     7cc5e4f8 00000050 40137a0c d4dfbad7 40128bdd  
I/DEBUG   (  231):     7cc5e508 40156147 7cc5e51c ffffff60 401252e9  
I/DEBUG   (  231):     7cc5e518 40156147 40159d2a ffffff60 40164388  
I/DEBUG   (  231):     7cc5e528 78af23b8 401261f5 0000008c 0000420c  
I/DEBUG   (  231):     7cc5e538 40125f95 78aec3b8 789d9e28 409a71b0  
I/DEBUG   (  231):     7cc5e548 7cc5e948 00000006 60000004 789d9e3c  
I/DEBUG   (  231):     7cc5e558 00000000 40123d21 00000000 407b7059  
I/DEBUG   (  231):     7cc5e568 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  231):     7cc5e578 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  231): 
I/DEBUG   (  231): code around pc:
I/DEBUG   (  231):     40138134 e8bd00f0 e3700a01 912fff1e e2600000  
I/DEBUG   (  231):     40138144 ea006e48 e92d50f0 e3a07f43 ef000000  
I/DEBUG   (  231):     40138154 e8bd50f0 e3700a01 912fff1e e2600000  
I/DEBUG   (  231):     40138164 ea006e40 e92d50f0 e3a070ee ef000000  
I/DEBUG   (  231):     40138174 e8bd50f0 e3700a01 912fff1e e2600000  
I/DEBUG   (  231):     40138184 ea006e38 f200429a bf0080b9 f040f891  
I/DEBUG   (  231):     40138194 4001e92d f2c02a04 2a1080a5 8093f2c0  
I/DEBUG   (  231):     401381a4 f2c02a20 2a408088 ea4fdb7f f1bc1c92  
I/DEBUG   (  231):     401381b4 dd6c0f0a 0600e92d 0f40f1bc f500dd4a  
I/DEBUG   (  231):     401381c4 f5016e80 ebae7920 ea4f0e09 ea4f5e4e  
I/DEBUG   (  231):     401381d4 f50e5e5e ebbc7e20 dd3b1f9e f04fbfc4  
I/DEBUG   (  231):     401381e4 ebd9090a dd35199e 0a0eeb01 0a3ff02a  
I/DEBUG   (  231):     401381f4 1c9eebac bfd245e1 0c09ebac f04f46e1  
I/DEBUG   (  231):     40138204 f8910c00 f891f240 f921f280 f921028d  
I/DEBUG   (  231):     40138214 f8da428d f1b93000 f9000901 f900028d  
I/DEBUG   (  231):     40138224 f10a428d d1ee0a40 0f00f1bc f5bcd02b  
I/DEBUG   (  231): 
I/DEBUG   (  231): code around lr:
I/DEBUG   (  231):     4012918c 447b4b13 42b3e010 6a1ed10e 44784811  
I/DEBUG   (  231):     4012919c ec84f7fb ea0cf00d 46224631 efcef00e  
I/DEBUG   (  231):     401291ac d00a3001 e00b2400 2b00681b 480ad1eb  
I/DEBUG   (  231):     401291bc 44782403 ec72f7fb f001e002 6804fa23  
I/DEBUG   (  231):     401291cc fa20f001 46206005 bf00bd70 0003b226  
I/DEBUG   (  231):     401291dc 0003b21a 0003b212 0003b1ee bf7ef7ff  
I/DEBUG   (  231):     401291ec 4a3e4b3d e92d447b b08b43f0 4606589c  
I/DEBUG   (  231):     401291fc 6823460d 930946a1 fa04f001 8000f8d0  
I/DEBUG   (  231):     4012920c d0482d00 f0104628 280ff91b d8444604  
I/DEBUG   (  231):     4012921c ffe4f7ff d1064286 4629200f e8d6f00d  
I/DEBUG   (  231):     4012922c d03c2800 482ee02e f7fb4478 482debb6  
I/DEBUG   (  231):     4012923c e0154478 d11342b0 482b6a06 f7fb4478  
I/DEBUG   (  231):     4012924c 4a2aec2e 46332120 a801447a f992f013  
I/DEBUG   (  231):     4012925c a8012101 fcb0f01a 46061c42 e011d104  
I/DEBUG   (  231):     4012926c 28006800 e02cd1e6 46294630 f00d4622  
I/DEBUG   (  231):     4012927c 1c43e912 d11e4607 f9c4f001 29046801  
I/DEBUG   (  231): !@dumpstate -k -t -z -d -o /data/log/dumpstate_app_native -m 15213
```

Comment: Have you checked the code on another device?

Comment: Yes both x86 and arm and crashes on both